# recyclerview item click listener with sqlite java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I would like to get data from the box which click on on the recycler view to go into a another activity to display.
I have tried to flow this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GPUpvcU1FE&t=399s&ab_channel=PracticalCoding i dont understand at 6:16.
Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQKq9RHMS_0&ab_channel=Stevdza-San i cannot get the data to pass to the new activity.

Main code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_staff_home);

        DB=new mainTextDBHelper(this);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        Title=new ArrayList<>();
        description=new ArrayList<>();
        radiogroup=new ArrayList<>();
        adapter=new recyclerviewAdapter(this,Title,description,radiogroup,listener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        displaydata();
        setOnClickListner();

 private void setOnClickListner() {
        listener=new recyclerviewAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, int position) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),cardviewclickon.class);
                intent.putExtra("Title",Title.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
    }

    private void displaydata() {
        Cursor cursor=DB.getdata();
        if(cursor.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(staff_home.this,"No Entry Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else{
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                Title.add(cursor.getString(1));
                description.add(cursor.getString(2));
                radiogroup.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
        }

    }
```

recyclerview Adapter code

```
public class recyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerviewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList Title_id,description_id,radiogroup_id;
    private RecyclerViewClickListener listener;

    public recyclerviewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList title_id, ArrayList description_id, ArrayList radiogroup_id,RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        Title_id = title_id;
        this.description_id = description_id;
        this.radiogroup_id = radiogroup_id;
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public recyclerviewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.userentry,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull recyclerviewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.Title_id.setText(String.valueOf(Title_id.get(position)));
        holder.description_id.setText(String.valueOf(description_id.get(position)));
        holder.radiogroup_id.setText(String.valueOf(radiogroup_id.get(position)));
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,cardviewclickon.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Title_id.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView Title_id,description_id,radiogroup_id;
        CardView cardView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            description_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
            radiogroup_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textsrverity);
            cardView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
                }
            };

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface RecyclerViewClickListener{
        void onClick(View v,int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your onclicklistener is created after instantiating the `recyclerviewAdapter` so you are passing null.  Call `setOnClickListner` before creating the adapter.  And  this statement `new View.OnClickListener() ` without assignment does nothing.  Looks like the `cardView` listener is the one actually starting the activity which passes no data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from one activity to other you can use `PutExtra()` method of the `Intent` class As I can see you are doing everything pretty much well but you have to catch these extra from the class you are passing like:- I want to pass data from `recyclerView` to `CardViewClass` I can do it like:-

In RecyclerView.java file:-

```
public void sendDataAndOpen(String title) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CardViewClass.class);
   intent.putExtraString("Title",Title); // You can use putExtra to put any datatype
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

In CardViewClass.java file (Lets catch our passing data):-

```
public void onCreate(...) {

....

String title = getIntent().getExtraString("Title") // You can also use ExtraPut and // Must use Same Id
// Use data as you want
.....

}
```